# Simple Facebook Javascript post to stream example?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm trying to post to user stream, without user prompt. I cannot manage to find a code that works. Facebook JSDK is already loaded and I will insert the code inside:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
```

to make sure the user is already logged to my application. Could you provide an example of publishing to the user stream using the `publish_stream` permission?

Comment: While what you are asking for is already there in the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/), be aware that Facebook recommends a user-initiated sharing model. For more, read the [`publish_stream` permission description](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/#extended_perms)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**With Dialog**

You need to use the Feed Dialog, with `FB.ui()`:

```
function postToFeed() {
    // calling the API ...
    var obj = {
        method: 'feed',
        link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
        picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
        name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
        caption: 'Reference Documentation',
        description: 'Using Dialogs to interact with users.'
    };

    function callback(response) {
        document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
    }

    FB.ui(obj, callback);
}
```

Documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

**Without Dialog**

To make a post without the Dialog you need to use the `FB.api()`:

```
var body = 'Reading JS SDK documentation';
FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: body }, function(response) {
  if (!response || response.error) {
    alert('Error occured');
  } else {
    alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
  }
});
```

Documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/

**Direct URL**

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?
  app_id=APP_ID&
  link=https://YOUR_DOMAIN&
  picture=http://YOUR_DOMAIN/image.jpg&
  name=Facebook%20Dialogs&
  caption=API%20Dialogs&
  description=Using%20Dialogs%20to%20interact%20with%20users.&
  redirect_uri=http://YOUR_DOMAIN/response
```

Documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Comment: "The Feed Dialog prompts the user to publish an individual story" I don't want to prompt the user. I want to post to stream without user prompt. Won't using that code open a popup?

Comment: @Liso22, i also include a Direct URL example. If you find this answer helpful, you can upvote and select it as the correct one.

Comment: Error occured:Unsupported post request.
i got that error using api any suggestion