# Facebook breaking changes to post on users wall

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I am working currently on an application to post on Facebook wall automatically.
I went through all blogs and articles that talking about this type of applications.
Finally I came out with this result. Firstly I have to authenticate the user and grant the required permissions such as shown in my JavaScript code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Title</title>
        <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){


var appId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
var redirectUrl = "http://www.mydomain.com";

if (0 <= window.location.href.indexOf ("error_reason"))
{
$(document.body).append ("<p>Authorization denied!</p>");
return;
}

window.fbAsyncInit = function(){

FB.init({
appId : appId,
status : true,
cookie : true,
oauth : true,
channel: true,
channelURL: "http://www.mydomain.com/channel/"
});


FB.getLoginStatus (onCheckLoginStatus);
};


(function(d)
{
var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
}(document));


function onCheckLoginStatus (response)
{
if (response.status != "connected")
{
top.location.href = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" + appId + "&redirect_uri=" + encodeURIComponent (redirectUrl) + "&scope=publish_stream,email,user_birthday,publish_actions,offline_access";
}
else
{
// Start the application (this is just demo code)! ///////////////////////////////////
$(document.body).append ("<p>Authorized!</p>");
FB.api('/me', function (response) {
$(document.body).append ("<pre>" + JSON.stringify (response, null, "\t") + "</pre>");
});
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
}
}
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

After the user's session has been successfully authenticated and he accepted my permissions requests to post on his behalf, it comes to the hardest piece of code which I worked around for more than two weeks moving from one site to another one. But it's useless.

I found the following code to publish posts but only on the currently logged-in user's wall:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function updateStatusViaJavascriptAPICalling(){
        var status  =   document.getElementById('status').value;
            FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: status }, function(response) {
                if (!response || response.error) {
                     alert('Error occured');
                } else {
                     alert('Status updated Successfully');
                }
           });
    }
```

It works like a charm but when I change `/me/feed` to another Facebook uid it says that publishing as this application to other users is not working. However I tried to put app access token and user access token and changed `post` to `PHP feed dialog` but also in vain.

I tried all codes either PHP or JavaScript to accomplish this job but unfortunately nothing worked. Especially after Facebook prevented applications developers to post on friends' walls.

All I need is to post on behalf of my users on their wall automatically even if they are offline. How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Posting to friends' feed stopped working on Feb 6th 2013](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/14792062/posting-to-friends-feed-stopped-working-on-feb-6th-2013)

Comment: Thanks MIchael for your comment, but in the article you mentioned i didn't get a clear answer to implement. How can i convert this `If you want to allow people to post to their friends' timelines, invoke the feed dialog. Stories that include friends via user mentions tagging or action tagging will show up on the friend’s timeline (assuming the friend approves the tag)` into a working code to re enable posting to users wall again

Answer (score 0):

You CANNOT post to user's friends through the graph Api. Only way to achieve this is to invoke the Javascript SDK Feed Dialog.

Regarding the access tokens, you can extend the short lived access token for a long lived access token [ that holds good for 60 days ]. Read more : http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Comment: Thanks Abhas for your reply. But i am still newbie to the coding. Could you please make this statement clear for me `invoke the Javascript SDK Feed Dialogِ` by giving me a piece of code which achieves that.<br /> Regarding the access token, which one should be used to post to users wall, **App Access Token** or **User Access Token**

Comment: @AmrAli here is an example of Feed Dialog: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287577/simple-facebook-javascript-post-to-stream-example/11288325#11288325

Comment: @Philip "The Feed Dialog prompts the user to publish an individual story" and the user has to be logged into facebook. I don't want to prompt the user. I want to post without user prompt and when the user is offline

Comment: @igy @Abhas @Philip When i used the Feed Dialog, with `FB.ui():` same problem is still existing that i can't post to any user exept the currently logged one and even when i try to inject the code with the receipt it doesn't work. By any how i need to post on behalf of my users on their wall automatically even if they are offline. HELP

Comment: @AmrAli I think that's not possible, not any more. According the new rules you need to use the ui Dialog for this.

Comment: @Philip i know a lot of apps which can do this job till now. There is no way to play around via access tokens, session data or any thing